Problems with JSON generated menu. The links are not clickable. Any ideas?
So, I made a website with different language content I pull from json files (e.g en.json, fr.json etc.). Of course I also wanted to translate the menu points so that when someone chooses a language, the page would reload and that would be updated as well. In my en.json file there would be objects like
"m-first-steps":"First Steps", etc.
And I can see the correct menu points for each language on my page but I can not click them.
My idea was to generate clickable anchor menu points.
Clicking the menu point (e.g. "First Steps) is supposed to bring the user to the section on the page (href + #id).
        <div class="nav-container">
            <span class="logo lato-bold">DacHOW<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i></span>
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav-ul">
                    <li class="nav-link" ><a href="#home">HELLO</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-first-steps"><a href="#first-steps"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-asylum"><a href="#asylum"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-financial-aid"><a href="#financial-aid"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-healthcare"><a href="#healthcare"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-education"><a href="#education"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-support"><a href="#support"></a></li>
                    <li class="nav-link" lang-attribute="m-contacts"><a href="#contacts"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <span class="hamburger-menu material-symbols-outlined"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></span>
        
            <div class="dropdown-language container">
                <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbtn">
                    English
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" id="arrow"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="index.html" onclick="changeLanguage('en')">English</a>
                  <a href="index.html" onclick="changeLanguage('fr')">French</a>
                  <a href="index.html" onclick="changeLanguage('ar')">Arabic</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
              </div> 
        </div>

When I noticed, I tried to find help from chat GPT who advised to add js functions to pull the menu content specifically. I added that to my JS but ut did not help. I am a beginner and am struggling to give the right prompts to Chat GPT which I think might be the issue.
//          NAVIGATION          //


// Mobile Hamburger Navbar: opening on click
const hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector(".hamburger-menu");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
// Hamburger Menu opens and closes when clicked 
hamburgerMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    nav.classList.toggle("active");
});

// When on mobile, once user clicked the menu point they want to go to, it closes
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link a');
navLinks.forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nav.classList.remove('active');
  });
});





//      LANGUAGE DROPDOWN SELECTION BUTTON       //


// Language Dropdown 
const dropdownBtn = document.getElementById("dropbtn");
const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById("dropdown-content");
const toggleArrow = document.getElementById("arrow");

// Toggle dropdown function
const toggleDropdown = function () {
  dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");
  toggleArrow.classList.toggle("arrow");
};

// Toggle dropdown open/close when dropdown button is clicked
dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  toggleDropdown();
});

// Close dropdown when dom element is clicked 
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (dropdownMenu.classList.contains("show")) {
    toggleDropdown();
  }
});




//      LANGUAGE SELECT/SAVE/CHANGE FUNCTIONALITY       //





// Function to save the language preference in localStorage
function setLanguagePreference(lang) {
    localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
}




// Function to update the site content based on selected language
function updateContent(langData) {
    document.querySelectorAll('[lang-attribute]').forEach(element => {
        const key = element.getAttribute('lang-attribute');
        element.textContent = langData[key];
    });
}



// Function to fetch language data from json files
async function fetchLanguageData(lang) {
    const response = await fetch(`languages/${lang}.json`);
    return response.json();
}









// CHAT GPT ADDED: Function to update the menu items with language-specific text
async function updateMenuItems(lang) {
    const langData = await fetchLanguageData(lang);
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

    navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        const menuItemKey = link.getAttribute('lang-attribute');
        const menuItemText = langData[menuItemKey];
        link.querySelector('a').textContent = menuItemText;
    });
}

// CHAT GPT ADDED: Call updateMenuItems() on page load
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const userPreferredLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language') || 'en';
    await updateMenuItems(userPreferredLanguage);
});







// Function to change language from one to another 
async function changeLanguage(lang) {
    setLanguagePreference(lang);
    const langData = await fetchLanguageData(lang);
    updateContent(langData);

    // Update language displayed in the dropdown button 
    const languageNames = {
        'en': 'English',
        'fr': 'French',
        'ar': 'Arabic'
    };
    document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = `${languageNames[lang]} <i class="fa fa-caret-down" id="arrow"></i>`;
    
    // Change text direction based on the selected language
    if (lang === 'ar') {
        document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
        } else {
        document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
        }
}


// Call updateContent() on page load
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    const userPreferredLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language') || 'en';
    const langData = await fetchLanguageData(userPreferredLanguage);
    updateContent(langData);

    // Update language displayed in the dropdown button
    const languageNames = {
        'en': 'English',
        'fr': 'French',
        'ar': 'Arabic'
    };
    document.getElementById('dropbtn').innerHTML = `${languageNames[userPreferredLanguage]} <i class="fa fa-caret-down" id="arrow"></i>`;
    // Change text direction based on the preferred language
    if (userPreferredLanguage === 'ar') {
        document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl');
    } else {
        document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'ltr');
    }
});






Please, do you have an idea how to make my navigation links clickable?
I think the problem is that the menu links are json generated so in the html the anchor links are empty. I added one not json generated and just put some text and it could be clicked.

Where is your JSON ?

Your menu links contain no text <a href="#support"></a>.  Is that being filled in somewhere?

It is filled from my json files (en.json fr.json etc.) and is successfully displayed- but unclickable.

Are you filling the <a> tag or are you filling the <li>?  If you're filling the <li>, then you would have to wrap an <a> around it.

@TimRoberts this was it. Simple as that. THANK YOU!

You shouldn't have both a href and an onclick event on an anchor.
<a href="index.html" onclick="changeLanguage('en')">English</a>

It should be either one or the other.
Also your href just reloads your main program index.html so it's best to remove the hrefs.
So you can either do this...
<a onclick="changeLanguage('en');">English</a>

Or this...
<a href="javascript:changeLanguage('en');">English</a>

They both should work although the later is more "sensible" so to speak, because it's an anchor and you're expected to make use of the href.
Oh wait, did you actually mean for the page to reload after changing language?

Hi there, I think I do need both (but could be super wrong) - the page needs to reload after changing language and the href to get to the right page section after clicking on the menu point (href + #id). But I will try later like you said, maybe it can work...thank you!

Make var json_languages = [] and contain with data from JSON that we aren't seeing right now.
Make it clear with F12 as dev mode network statuses for load languages/en.json, languages/fr.json, languages/ar.json and languages/undefined.json for other'
Also I do not understand was it generated at first or not
Check out this method, it might not work, and there are importance to make sentence separated or 3-7 words separated requests, it should be ethical to Google Servers etc.
// translate text2 from english to russian automatically for example
const translateText = async (text) => {
  let url = `https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=ru&dt=t&q=${text}`;
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = await response.json();
  return data[0][0][0] + ". ";
}

There are problem with translation and clickability. Try to order the datum into one variable and then regenerate from that every new time. Or You can make an array of selectors to loop through this, then translate each of the chunk itself.
Be sure to ask GPT strictly and do follow the original Stack Overflow Rules, like instruction said.

This is not an answer, and should have been posed as a comment/question.

check it out, I was edited
